# Python Selenium Chrome Webdriver Not Working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com')
```

I have already installed chrome driver and selenium using pip command

The message show

[image]

Now what will be the solution to fix this ?

Comment: What version of selenium have you installed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your chrome application from settings by open that link in your installed chrome : chrome://settings/help